# How to use react-router-redux routeActions?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm trying to modify the example code of react-router-redux.
https://github.com/rackt/react-router-redux/blob/master/examples/basic/components/Home.js

this is my Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
    onSubmit(props) {
        this.props.routeActions.push('/foo');    
    }
}
```

I also have a mapDispatchToProps for it.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({ routeActions },dispatch);
}
```

When i called onSubmit function, I got an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.routeActions.push is not a function
```

If i remove this.props in onSubmit, the key in the URL changed but its still on the same page.
From `localhost:8080/#/?_k=iwio19` to `localhost:8080/#/?_k=ldn1ew`

Anyone know how to fix it?
Appreciate it.

Comment: Show us your complete Home.js please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think `routeActions` are passed as `props`. What you want to do is this:

```
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux'

this.props.dispatch(routeActions.push('/foo'));
```

Comment: This is indeed how you should do it. The problem comes up when you mapDispatchToProps and still want to use dispatch. for example connect(null, { someAction })(YourComponent) will remove dispatch from props. Any idea how to use routeActions in this scenario?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't catch that the first time. What if you moved your route action to your actions file and called the route function from there. That way it wouldn't interfere with mapDispatchToProps and you could reuse the action in multiple components

Answer (score 9):

To provide a little more explicit answer and the answer to my own question in the comment.

Yes you can do

```
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux'

this.props.dispatch(routeActions.push('/foo));
```

However as I mentioned mapDispatchToProps will override this.
To fix this you can bind the routeActions like so:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        routeActions: bindActionCreators(routeActions, dispatch),
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent)
```

Now you can do: `this.props.routeActions.push('/foo')`

Just FYI this can be done even neater

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        ...bindActions({routeActions, anotherAction}, dispatch)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think routeActions is no longer part of react router redux. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: It says, `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)` ,where as import {push} is working fine

Answer (score 7):

As for react-router-redux [v4](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/releases/tag/v4.0.0):

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

export class ExampleContainer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    changeRoute: React.PropTypes.func,
  };

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      changeRoute: (url) => dispatch(push(url)),
      dispatch,
    };
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleContainer);
```

then:

```
this.props.changeRoute('/foo');
```

Comment: Please @Mikhail how do I navigate programmatically if I am using browserHistory in my Router component? I just tried your solution but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get it working by doing this

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux'

export const Cmpt = React.createClass({ //code })

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    push: routeActions.push,
    //all your other action creators here
  }, dispatch)
}

export const CmptContainer = connect({}, mapDispatchToProps)(Cmpt)
```

Then you can use push via props
`this.props.push('some/cool/route')`

Comment: this also addresses @Michiel question

Answer (score 1):

#### More Concisely

For these examples, I'd curry the mapDispatchToProps function like so:

**bindActionDispatchers.js**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

/** curries mapDispatchToProps with bindActionCreators to simplify React action dispatchers. */
export default function bindActionDispatchers(actionCreators) {
  if(typeof actionCreators === 'function')
    return (dispatch, ownProps) => bindActionCreators(actionCreators(ownProps), dispatch)
  return dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}
```

**Foo.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import bindActionDispatchers from './bindActionDispatchers'
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux'
import * as appActions from './actions'

const Foo = ({ routeActions ...appActions }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={routeActions.push('/route')}>Route</button>
    <button onClick={appActions.hello('world')}>Hello</button>
  </div>
)

export default connect(null, bindActionDispatchers({ routeActions, ...appActions }))(Foo)
```

I packaged this into a lightweight npm package [bind-action-dispatchers](https://npmjs.com/packages/bind-action-dispatchers) complete with unit tests and sanity checks. To use this version install with:

**`npm i -S bind-action-dispatchers`**

and import the function with:

**`import bindActionDispatchers from 'bind-action-dispatchers'`**